# MatLab GUI Troubles: Calculating an Integral

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have created a matlab GUI in which a user selects a variable to integrate with respect to, inputs the equation, and lower and upper limits. When my code goes to calculate the integral on pushbutton Callback, I get an error I don't understand.

This is the line of code causing the error:

```
i1 = int( eval(get(handles.edit1,'string')),
          (handles.respectvar), 
          get(handles.edit3),
          get(handles.edit2)
        );
```

> %respactvar is the user-selected variable, and edit3 and edit2 are the lower and upper limits.

And this is the error message:

> Error using sym>tomupad (line 1135)
>   Conversion to 'sym' from 'struct' is not possible.
>
> Error in sym (line 151)
>                   S.s = tomupad(x);
>
> Error in sym/int (line 142)
>      b = sym(b);
>
> Error in projectCALC>pushbutton1_Callback (line 376)
>       i1=int(eval(get(handles.edit1,'string')),(handles.respectvar),get(handles.edit3),get(handles.edit2));
>
> Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
>           feval(varargin{:});
>
> Error in projectCALC (line 42)
>       gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
>
> Error in @(hObject,eventdata)projectCALC('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
>
> Error while evaluating UIControl Callback

Thank you!

Comment: You need to get the strings from the edit boxes containing your integration limits and convert them to a numeric data type. `get(handles.edit3)` will just return a structure of the properties of the object.

Comment: Also, using `eval` is inefficient and *unsafe*, especially if you're evaluating something that the user input in the box. What if it's a `system` call? Are you sure you can't avoid using `eval`?

Comment: @AndrasDeak Though this doesn't address the security concern, I don't think there's any way around `eval` for this kind of thing. I'm almost positive `str2func` is just a wrapper for `eval` but I don't have MATLAB available to check.

Comment: @excaza [the doc says `str2func` could be used instead of `eval` in many cases](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7asp2-1), suggesting that it's better. And on R2012b `str2func('system(''echo oops!'')')` will issue a warning (to be an error in a future release) and not execute the command (OK, of course `str2func('@() system(''echo oops!'')')` can be evaluated by `int` to cause harm still). Also, `str2func` is a compiled built-in.

Comment: @excaza Thank you for your help! I put the get(handles.edit3) and the other one inside of a str2double(). I am no longer getting errors, but my results box displays NaN no matter what I type in.
    i1=int(eval(get(handles.edit1,'string')),(handles.respectvar),str2double(get(handles.edit3)),str2double(get(handles.edit2)));

Comment: @AndrasDeak I am relatively new to programming, as this is my first class I've taken with it. If there is anything besides eval that you suggest I use, I'll take the suggestion! I tried replacing the eval with str2func, but a warning said it was not a valid function name.

Comment: @CarlyHauser I think I've figured out all (most?) of your problems. I added an answer, let me know if I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

The first problem, as [@excaza noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608638/matlab-gui-troubles-calculating-an-integral?noredirect=1#comment60816122_36608638), is that you forgot to `get` the `string` property of the last two edit boxes, while you did this for the first one.

The second problem is that `eval` is very inefficient, and, in your case, very unsafe. What if somebody wrote a `system()` call into the editbox, erasing your hard drive?

The third problem is that even with `eval` or `str2func`, `int` requires its first argument to be a symbolic expression. This is a good thing: you don't actually have to use `eval`, you just have to convert your first string to a `sym`.

The fourth problem is that `handles.respectvar` also seems to be a GUI object, so you might need to `get()` some property for it in order to be able to use it as an integration variable.

Assuming that my suspicion is correct, and your `edit1` contains a string like `'3*x+y'`, `edit2` and `edit3` are limits such as `'1'` and `'3'`, and `handles.respectvar` has a property that evaluates to `'x'`, then you should be calling

```
formula = sym(get(handles.edit1,'string'));
variable = handles.respectvar;    %// more likely: get(handles.respectvar,...)
lim1 = str2double(get(handles.edit3,'string'));
lim2 = str2double(get(handles.edit2,'string'));
i1 = int(formula,variable,lim1,lim2);
```

A few notes:

- Don't be afraid of using temporary variables where it helps in readability.
- I converted the `formula` from `sym` to `string`, otherwise you get a warning or an error (depending on MATLAB version)
- I left the order of `lim1` <-> `edit3`, `lim2` <-> `edit2`. Make sure this is indeed what you want, and orders are not reversed.
- I converted the integration limits to `double`, but it seems that `sym/int` will also accept string input as the limit variables, so this is mostly for clarity.

Comment: Thank you so much! As I was reading around on the internet, I did learn of how unsafe eval can be, but at the time I did not know of any other methods.Treating it as a symbol in the first place makes it much better. I will remember this in the rest of my project!

Comment: @CarlyHauser I'm glad I could help:) There's almost always a better alternative to `eval`. Good luck with the rest!